# запрос php к mysql записать строки в базу

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. У меня имеется код, который выводит два текстовых поля и одно поле для ввода текста. При нажатии кнопки, данные из поля для ввода записываются в таблицу. Работает на коде ниже.

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $text = !empty($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : null;
        foreach ($text as $idt => $pages) {
            if ($pages != NULL) {     
                $todb = $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO extend (id, pages) VALUES ("' . $idt . '", "' . $pages . '") 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pages = "' . $pages . '"');
            }
        }
        echo '<br>Команда выполнена!<br><br>';
    }   
      $todb = $mysqli->query('SELECT 
      nal.id AS id,
      nal.name AS name,
      extend.id AS id2,
      extend.pages AS pages
      FROM nal LEFT JOIN extend 
      ON nal.id = extend.id 
      WHERE nal.remainder > 0
      ORDER BY name ASC');
      echo '<table class="raz">';
      while ($row = $todb->fetch_array())
      { echo '<tr><td>'.$row[id].'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$row[name].'</td>';
          echo '<td><input type="text" name="text['.$row[id].']" value="'.$row[pages].'" maxlength="5" size="6"><br></td></tr>';
          $count++;
      }
        echo '</table>';    
        echo 'строк выведено: '.$count.'<br>';

    echo'<button type="submit" name="submit">Нажать</button></form>';
```

Я решил немного увеличить таблицу и поставить несколько полей для ввода.

```
$todb = $mysqli->query('SELECT 
  nal.id AS id,
  nal.name AS name,
  tempextend.id AS id2,
  tempextend.pages AS pages,
  tempextend.perep AS perep,
  tempextend.orig AS orig,
  tempextend.pere AS pere
  FROM nal LEFT JOIN tempextend 
  ON nal.id = tempextend.id 
  WHERE nal.remainder > 0');
  while ($row = $todb->fetch_array())
  { echo '<tr><td>'.$row[id].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$row[name].'</td>';
      echo '<td><input type="text" name="pages['.$row[id].']" value="'.$row[pages].'" maxlength="5" size="5"><br></td>';
      echo '<td><input type="text" name="perep['.$row[id].']" value="'.$row[perep].'" maxlength="15" size="7"><br></td>';
      echo '<td><input type="text" name="orig['.$row[id].']" value="'.$row[orig].'" maxlength="19" size="12"><br></td>';
      echo '<td><input type="text" name="pere['.$row[id].']" value="'.$row[pere].'" maxlength="19" size="12"><br></td></tr>';
      $count++;
  }
echo '</table>';
echo 'строк выведено: '.$count.'<br>';  
echo'<button type="submit" name="submit">Нажать</button></form>';
```

А при нажатии кнопки срабатывает вот такой код.

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $pages = !empty($_POST['pages']) ? $_POST['pages'] : null;
        $pereplet = !empty($_POST['perep']) ? $_POST['perep'] : null;
        $orig = !empty($_POST['orig']) ? $_POST['orig'] : null;
        $pere = !empty($_POST['pere']) ? $_POST['izdat_perevod'] : null;
        foreach ($pages as $idt => $izdat_orig) {
            if ($pages != NULL || $perep != NULL || $orig != NULL || $pere != NULL) {     
                $todb = $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO tempextend (id, pages, perep, orig, pere) 
VALUES ("' . $idt . '", "' . $pages . '", "' . $perep . '", "' . $orig . '", "' . $pere . '")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pages = "' . $pages . '", perep = "' . $perep . '", orig = "' . $orig . '", pere = "' . $pere . '"');
            }
        }
    echo 'Команда выполнена!<br><br>';
    }
```

И в итоге ничего не происходит. Меня смущает foreach тут, не понимаю какие данные там нужно подставить. Как вообще можно обработать такой запрос?

Comment: В цикле while формируется несколько полей pages[1],pages[2],pages[3]  и т.д. А при сабмите Вы чекаете только поле pages. К чему там foreach и правда не понятно, тем более такой код не сработает, или сработает не так как надо

Comment: да, у меня список полей выходит, окола 700, и в каких нужно строках я правлю. Но я пытаюсь теперь сделать так, чтобы у меня было не одно поле для правки, а несколько.

Comment: Почему вы после выполнения запросов не проверяете на наличие ошибок (возвращают false). надо обязательно проверять на ошибки и если они есть выводить куда либо сообщения об этих ошибках. без этого вы никогда не поймете что что то идет не так

Comment: **Вы не боитесь sql инъекций вставляя данные пришедшие со стороны прямо в запросы?**

Comment: нет, этот код только для меня лично в админ панели, в которую больше никто не попадет. Поэтому тут я только себя могу винить.